# mysqldump by query, then use to update remote database

Tags: command-line, mysql

I have a database containing a very large table including binary data which I want to update on a remote machine, once a day.  Rather than dumping the entire table, transferring and recreating it on the remote machine, I want to dump only the updates, then use that dump to *update* the remote machine.

I already understand that I can produce the dump file as such.

```
mysqldump -u user -p=pass  --quick --result-file=dump_file \
          --where "Updated >= one_day_ago" \
          database_name table_name
```

1) Does the resulting "restore" on the *remote machine*

```
mysql -u user -p=pass database_name < dump_file
```

only update the necessary rows?  Or are there other adverse effects?

2)  Is this the best way to do this? (I am unable to pipe to the server directly and using `--host` option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only dump rows where the `WHERE` clause is true, then you will only get a .sql file that contains the values you want to update. So you will never get duplicate values if you use the current export options. However, inserting these into a database will not work. You will have to use the commandline parameter `--replace`, otherwise, if you dump your database and a row with id `6` in table `table1` and try to import this into your other database, you'll get an error on duplicates if a row already has id = `6`. Using the `--replace` parameter, it will overwrite older values, which can only happen if there is a new one (according to your `WHERE` clause).

So to quickly answer:

1. Yes, this will restore on the remote machine, but only if you saved using --replace (this will restore the latest version of the file you have)
2. I am not entirely sure if you can pipe backups. According to [this website](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysqldump-pipe-mysql-output-and-input/), you can, but I have never tried it before.